# Is it possible to make the remesh modifier block size constant?

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, scripting, modifiers

I am interested in using the Remesh modifier for stylized modelling, however there is a major flaw in the fact that the Remesh Modifier appears to only take vertices and face area etc. into account when calculating block sizes. I really would like to have a way to  make this size constant.

I am considering using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and vertex groups, however this would be a major pain. Is there any other way to do this? I am open to Python solutions as well.

Comment: How will the "block size" be defined? My idea would be to take the biggest object and find the appropriate octree&scale values and impose that to others. The trick to avoid running the modifier upon joined objects would be to give each one the biggest object's bounding box as remeshing domain (http://imgur.com/mMIvCvq)

Comment: Have you tried that? It doesn't work AFAICT.

Comment: Yes, I made the linked image that way. To set the same bounding box domain for all the objects I simply copied the same four vertices in each object http://imgur.com/4bAdTvH.

Comment: So now if you edit them separately, they stay the same? That doesn't work if I remember correctly.

Comment: Here's my testfile http://www.filedropper.com/suzannebbox. It seems I can edit the mesh without any issue, but maybe I didn't stress-tested it enough. Let me know in which sense it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm, done right that might be good enough. You can add an answer. Looks pretty good.

Answer (score 4):

Remesh modifer use the object's bounding box to determine the size of the block (combined with the scale and the octree depth)

If you want to use just the built-in tools and no python, a possible, dirty, **workaround** could consist in altering each object bounding box to a fixed the one of a "remeshing box".

Create a box of the wanted size, delete faces (deleting edges is optional) and assign to the object a Remesh modifer with the target resolution.

[image]

Create/pick one object, move it inside the box. Apply scale.

[image]

Join the object with a duplicate of your cage. This way the mesh will inherit the modifiers with all the settings.

[image]

You can edit the object freely until it stays inside the box defined by the vertices.

[image]

[image]

**Cons:**

- The box can't be changed interactively.
- You have to duplicate and join the remeshing box for each object.

Comment: If nothing better shows up in the next few days, I'll accept this.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, anyway I'm not worried about that. I hope someone will come out with a more flexible solution too, mine is just a trick. I agree with leaving it open.

Comment: If your meshes are manifold and not intersecting, a boolean union on the "cage" would help: No need to apply scale and join, can edit transformation on object level, etc.

Comment: Or, even better, use an array modifier on A object, use object ofset set to B, and end cap also set to B. This is basically a mesh-combine modifier.